# If statement with both 'and' and 'or'

Tags: python, if-statement

I want my if statement to evaluate `True` if `answers[3] == 'Friday'` and if `answers[4]` equals either of `'13-15'` or `'15-17'`

Is below form correct?

```
if (answers[3] == 'Friday' and (answers[4] == '13-15' or answers[4] == '15-17')):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's correct, and you can use a `set` container in order to make the `or` statement more concise.

```
if answers[3] == 'Friday' and answers[4] in {'13-15', '15-17'}:
```